# MVC5: Async PartialView that has it's own controler and can recieve parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Basically my goal was to create a partial view that I could include in multiple pages and that would load it's own values depending on a parameter.  I couldnt find anything that directly allowed this behaviour exactly as I wanted it.
I succeeded in hacking my way to a successful result but being new to MVC I'm quite sure I did things wrong and I'd like to get some feedback I'm afraid to have something that works but is completely flawed.

In any page that need to display the panels I just have to do this

`@Html.Partial("_AsyncGroupList", valueOfParameterToPass)`
`@Html.Partial("_AsyncMailboxList", valueOfParameterToPass)`

And when I load the page I get exactly what I want.
[image]

To achieve this I had to do the following.

For both panels I need different PartialViews that looks almost exactly the same. In those PartialViews I have an ajax request that will load an other PartialView and put it inside the panel.  That second PartialView can be of any type and have it's own unique model.

In the following PartialView (_AsyncGroupList.cshtml) I am calling the ListController with the GroupList action and this will return a PartialView that will fill the content of the panel

```
//_AsyncGroupList.cshtml
@using MVCTest.Controllers;
@model int
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default ">           
        <div class="panel-heading">Groups</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p id="TheGroupsList"> <img src="../content/loading.gif" alt="Be patient..." /> LOADING... </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()   {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../List/ShowGroupsList",
            data: { id: @Model },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#TheGroupsList').html(response);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

And it the ListController

```
 public class ListController : Controller
{
       public ActionResult ShowGroupsList(int id)
      {
          var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
          timer.Start();
          while (timer.Elapsed.Seconds < id) { //just wait }           
          timer.Stop();
           //the partialView returned here could be any partialView with it's corresponding model.
          return PartialView("_ListOfThings", new TestlistModel(id) { Name = "Groups" });
      }

     public ActionResult ShowMailBoxList(int id)
    {              
       var timer= new  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
       timer.Start();
       while (timer.Elapsed.Seconds < id)  { //just wait }
       timer.Stop();
        return PartialView("_ListOfThings", new TestlistModel(id) { Name="MailBox"});
    }
```

I think I need the two level of PartialViews because they dont share the same model.  Also they could have their controller instead of sharing the same one.

But there it is.  Am I completely out to lunch on this one?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using the ajax calls?

Comment: @BillRuhl Because some of these panels communicate with external resources that could either timeout or take a long time to load.  So I need the web page to load fast and whatever panels are slow just have the loading spinner.